# One thousand copies of a random value in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have a cell in excel which refreshes every time I press F9. I want to have 1000 copies of this random variable in a column, then calculate the average. But it is very tedious to type in the actual value manually.

Is there an efficient method for this?

Comment: Look into the [RND](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/rnd.php) function

Comment: Also, sharing what you've tried so far and the code you have increases your chances of getting an answer dramatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets say that cell **B9** contains the value that is re-calculated at each calculation of the worksheet.  Also assume that we will store 1000 samples in **C1** thru **C1000**

```
Sub MontiCarlo()
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To 1000
        Application.Calculate
        Cells(i, 3).Value = Range("B9").Value
    Next i
    Range("D1").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(Range("C1:C1000"))
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do what I think you want to do:

```
Dim v As Variant
Dim i As Long
ReDim v(1 To 1000, 1 To 1)
For i = 1 To 1000
    v(i, 1) = Rnd()
Next
Range("A3").Resize(1000, 1) = v
Range("A1").Formula = "=AVERAGE(A3:A1002)"
```

Comment: Thanks, but my random variable is specific. It is the sum of other random variables, some of them are exponentially distributed, some of them not.